# how to create a rolling pivot table in python into a df?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df (sample is pasted here in the end).
I am looking to find which `tradePrice` had the most `tradeVolume` per each minute. this is a pivot table sent into a new df. 
the pivot table in xls looks like this:

```
              minute                
tradePrice  Data           0    1   10  Total Result    
12548   Sum - tradeVolume           3   3   
        Count - tradePrice          2   2   
12548.5 Sum - tradeVolume           1   1   
        Count - tradePrice          1   1   
12549   Sum - tradeVolume           1   1   
        Count - tradePrice          1   1   
12549.5 Sum - tradeVolume           95  95  
        Count - tradePrice          5   5   
12550   Sum - tradeVolume           6   6   
        Count - tradePrice          4   4   
12559   Sum - tradeVolume   93          93  
        Count - tradePrice  1           1   
12559.5 Sum - tradeVolume       1       1   
        Count - tradePrice      1       1   
12560   Sum - tradeVolume       5       5   
        Count - tradePrice      4       4   
12560.5 Sum - tradeVolume   3   5       8   
        Count - tradePrice  3   2       5   
12561   Sum - tradeVolume   4   5       9   
        Count - tradePrice  2   3       5   
12561.5 Sum - tradeVolume   3   2       5   
        Count - tradePrice  3   1       4   
12562   Sum - tradeVolume   9   7       16  
        Count - tradePrice  8   1       9   
12562.5 Sum - tradeVolume   6   2       8   
        Count - tradePrice  2   2       4   
12563   Sum - tradeVolume   2           2   
        Count - tradePrice  1           1   
Total Sum - tradeVolume     120 27  106 253 
Total Count - tradePrice    20  14  13  47
```

The result need to be a df something like this searching for the price with the most volume traded):

```
    Price   Volume
02:00:00 AM 12559   93
02:01:00 AM 12562   7
02:10:00 AM 12549.5 95
```

My question is:
1. how do I get this pivot into a 1 minute df?
2. how can I get the same result but per rolling time period (which can not be less than 1 min) so the expected result (which price was traded with the max volume) for the last 10 minutes is:

```
    Price   Volume
02:10:00 AM 12549.5 95
```

The sample data:

```
    dateTime    tradePrice  tradeVolume 1min    time_of_day_10  time_of_day_30  date    hour    minute
0   2017-09-19 02:00:04 12559   93  2017-09-19 02:00:00 02:00:00    02:00:00    2017-09-19  2   0
49  2017-09-19 02:00:11 12562   1   2017-09-19 02:00:00 02:00:00    02:00:00    2017-09-19  2   0
50  2017-09-19 02:00:12 12563   2   2017-09-19 02:00:00 02:00:00    02:00:00    2017-09-19  2   0
51  2017-09-19 02:00:12 12562   1   2017-09-19 02:00:00 02:00:00    02:00:00    2017-09-19  2   0
122 2017-09-19 02:00:34 12561.5 1   2017-09-19 02:00:00 02:00:00    02:00:00    2017-09-19  2   0
123 2017-09-19 02:00:34 12562   1   2017-09-19 02:00:00 02:00:00    02:00:00    2017-09-19  2   0
127 2017-09-19 02:00:34 12562   1   2017-09-19 02:00:00 02:00:00    02:00:00    2017-09-19  2   0
129 2017-09-19 02:00:35 12561   2   2017-09-19 02:00:00 02:00:00    02:00:00    2017-09-19  2   0
130 2017-09-19 02:00:35 12560.5 1   2017-09-19 02:00:00 02:00:00    02:00:00    2017-09-19  2   0
131 2017-09-19 02:00:35 12561.5 1   2017-09-19 02:00:00 02:00:00    02:00:00    2017-09-19  2   0
135 2017-09-19 02:00:39 12562   1   2017-09-19 02:00:00 02:00:00    02:00:00    2017-09-19  2   0
136 2017-09-19 02:00:39 12562   1   2017-09-19 02:00:00 02:00:00    02:00:00    2017-09-19  2   0
137 2017-09-19 02:00:43 12561.5 1   2017-09-19 02:00:00 02:00:00    02:00:00    2017-09-19  2   0
138 2017-09-19 02:00:43 12561   2   2017-09-19 02:00:00 02:00:00    02:00:00    2017-09-19  2   0
139 2017-09-19 02:00:43 12560.5 1   2017-09-19 02:00:00 02:00:00    02:00:00    2017-09-19  2   0
140 2017-09-19 02:00:43 12560.5 1   2017-09-19 02:00:00 02:00:00    02:00:00    2017-09-19  2   0
152 2017-09-19 02:00:45 12562   2   2017-09-19 02:00:00 02:00:00    02:00:00    2017-09-19  2   0
153 2017-09-19 02:00:46 12562.5 4   2017-09-19 02:00:00 02:00:00    02:00:00    2017-09-19  2   0
166 2017-09-19 02:00:58 12562   1   2017-09-19 02:00:00 02:00:00    02:00:00    2017-09-19  2   0
167 2017-09-19 02:00:58 12562.5 2   2017-09-19 02:00:00 02:00:00    02:00:00    2017-09-19  2   0
168 2017-09-19 02:01:00 12562   7   2017-09-19 02:01:00 02:00:00    02:00:00    2017-09-19  2   1
169 2017-09-19 02:01:00 12562.5 1   2017-09-19 02:01:00 02:00:00    02:00:00    2017-09-19  2   1
170 2017-09-19 02:01:00 12562.5 1   2017-09-19 02:01:00 02:00:00    02:00:00    2017-09-19  2   1
171 2017-09-19 02:01:00 12561.5 2   2017-09-19 02:01:00 02:00:00    02:00:00    2017-09-19  2   1
175 2017-09-19 02:01:03 12561   1   2017-09-19 02:01:00 02:00:00    02:00:00    2017-09-19  2   1
176 2017-09-19 02:01:03 12561   3   2017-09-19 02:01:00 02:00:00    02:00:00    2017-09-19  2   1
187 2017-09-19 02:01:07 12560.5 2   2017-09-19 02:01:00 02:00:00    02:00:00    2017-09-19  2   1
188 2017-09-19 02:01:08 12561   1   2017-09-19 02:01:00 02:00:00    02:00:00    2017-09-19  2   1
189 2017-09-19 02:01:10 12560   1   2017-09-19 02:01:00 02:00:00    02:00:00    2017-09-19  2   1
190 2017-09-19 02:01:10 12560   1   2017-09-19 02:01:00 02:00:00    02:00:00    2017-09-19  2   1
191 2017-09-19 02:01:10 12559.5 1   2017-09-19 02:01:00 02:00:00    02:00:00    2017-09-19  2   1
192 2017-09-19 02:01:11 12560   1   2017-09-19 02:01:00 02:00:00    02:00:00    2017-09-19  2   1
193 2017-09-19 02:01:12 12560   2   2017-09-19 02:01:00 02:00:00    02:00:00    2017-09-19  2   1
194 2017-09-19 02:01:12 12560.5 3   2017-09-19 02:01:00 02:00:00    02:00:00    2017-09-19  2   1
593 2017-09-19 02:10:00 12550   1   2017-09-19 02:10:00 02:10:00    02:00:00    2017-09-19  2   10
594 2017-09-19 02:10:00 12549.5 12  2017-09-19 02:10:00 02:10:00    02:00:00    2017-09-19  2   10
604 2017-09-19 02:10:12 12548.5 1   2017-09-19 02:10:00 02:10:00    02:00:00    2017-09-19  2   10
605 2017-09-19 02:10:15 12549.5 22  2017-09-19 02:10:00 02:10:00    02:00:00    2017-09-19  2   10
606 2017-09-19 02:10:16 12549.5 21  2017-09-19 02:10:00 02:10:00    02:00:00    2017-09-19  2   10
636 2017-09-19 02:10:45 12548   1   2017-09-19 02:10:00 02:10:00    02:00:00    2017-09-19  2   10
637 2017-09-19 02:10:47 12548   2   2017-09-19 02:10:00 02:10:00    02:00:00    2017-09-19  2   10
638 2017-09-19 02:10:47 12549.5 23  2017-09-19 02:10:00 02:10:00    02:00:00    2017-09-19  2   10
639 2017-09-19 02:10:48 12549.5 17  2017-09-19 02:10:00 02:10:00    02:00:00    2017-09-19  2   10
640 2017-09-19 02:10:49 12549   1   2017-09-19 02:10:00 02:10:00    02:00:00    2017-09-19  2   10
665 2017-09-19 02:10:58 12550   1   2017-09-19 02:10:00 02:10:00    02:00:00    2017-09-19  2   10
666 2017-09-19 02:10:58 12550   1   2017-09-19 02:10:00 02:10:00    02:00:00    2017-09-19  2   10
667 2017-09-19 02:10:58 12550   3   2017-09-19 02:10:00 02:10:00    02:00:00    2017-09-19  2   10
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible data. That way we can focus on solving the problem rather than spending time in re-creating the data.

Comment: isn't the sample data enough? can i upload a csv file?